# Git and iCloud files

Tags: git, github, icloud

I cloned a git repo to my desktop and was going about my project when I ran git status prior to pushing, and I started seeing a bunch of JSONs with the extension `.json.icloud`. Is it safe to delete these files? I would leave them be, but they create a lot of noise when adding files to my commits.

EDIT:
All of the file names are `/home_directory/.filename.json.icloud`

Comment: Do not use a cloud-synced directory to store a Git repository. The cloud-syncing software will damage the repository.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.gitignore` file to ignore any files you don't want to commit.